# How to enable 2 finger touchpad pinch to zoom gesture (not ctrl+/-) Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, multi-touch, zooming

It seems in 19.10 the touchscreen 2 finger zoom is finally working correctly out of the box. So why is same behavior not on the touchpad? Is there any driver, software, Ubuntu flavor, Linux distribution that can achieve this? This is the only thing that stops Linux from being my daily driver. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most 'drivers' are built into the linux kernel, or modules inserted into kernel, but detail beyond that cannot be provided I suspect with your given information. We don't however support non-Ubuntu flavors, nor generic GNU/Linux (other linux distribututions)

Comment: So that means native support will only be added in the future releases right? Also, I saw software like fusuma can configure touchpad behavior. Maybe there is a way/software similar to trick the system to think the pinch is from the screen?

Answer (score 0):

remove the libinput drivers and install the old synaptic drivers

install: xserver-xorg-input-synaptics and xserver-xorg-input-evdev

remove: xserver-xorg-input-libinput

Comment: What is this evdev? I installed the first one and it does improve experience but it does not answer my question. Also, is removing libinput  necessary?